# Excel VBA-Web scraping <a> Href

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I created a macro that Extract Data from web Page and then print it into an excel Sheet .
The code works fine for :

**Openning Web Page and changing from page into another**

but the problems is :

**I can't click on Href link to access to that specific Page**

the Html for  href is this :

```
<a class=onglet href="/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do">Scheduling</a>
```

and the html container of that `<a>` is this

```
 <TD width=200><TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" border=0>
   <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD width=11><IMG src="/cmh/cmh/image/Tab1gh.gif" width=11 
          height=20></TD>
        <TD background=/cmh/cmh/image/Tab1mat.gif align=center><A 
         class=onglet href="/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do? 
          fromSelect=true">Scheduling</A></TD>
        <TD width=11><IMG src="/cmh/cmh/image/Tab1dr.gif" width=11 
               height=20>
       </TD>
    </TR>
   </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
</TD>
```

My code :

```
Sub extt()

Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim itm As IHTMLElement
Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long, d As Long
Dim lastRow As Variant
Dim elemCollection As Object
Dim ele As Object
Dim eRow As Long
Dim f As Variant
Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim MPNum As Variant
Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet
'add the microsoft Internet Controls
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


 With IE

  .Visible = True
  .navigate "http://preSearchMOD.do? 
    clearBackList=true&CMH_NO_STORING_fromMenu=true"

 While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
   'we ensure that the web Page is loaded completely


  Set itm = IE.document.getElementsByName("searchById")(0)
     If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = Sheets("GDC").Range("C9").Value
  Set doc = IE.document


  Set tags = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

  For Each tagx In tags
     If tagx.src = "htmh/image/button_search.gif" Then
    tagx.Click
   End If
  Next
Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Debug.Print elemCollection.Length
'Debug.Print elemCollection.body.innerHTML


For Each tagx In elemCollection
    If tagx.href = "http/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do? 
  fromSelect=true" Then
    tagx.Click
  Debug.Print tagx.body.innerHTML
End If
Next

myPoints = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(3)
Range("A1").Value = myPoints

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
 On Error Resume Next

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

End With

Set IE = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

this code doesn't return anything and doesn't click on that href

```
Set elemCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Debug.Print elemCollection.Length
'Debug.Print elemCollection.body.innerHTML


For Each tagx In elemCollection
    If tagx.href = "http/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do? 
  fromSelect=true" Then
    tagx.Click
  Debug.Print tagx.body.innerHTML
End If
Next
```

and also I tried to see how many `<a>` in that HTML code and I found `76`
using  : `Debug.Print elemCollection.Length`

To resume : What I want is to reach that `<a>` and click on that href to get that  **Scheduling** page

anyone can light me in solving this ?

Comment: The URL you have used within your scraper is not accessible. The html elements you have pasted above are within an image which is (pasting an image containing html elements) strongly discouraged in SO. Try to paste raw elements so that it can be reused for test.

Comment: Hello @SIM yes it's not accesible because it is an internal web site Airbus local website, post edited

Comment: @SIM I found the solution and I answered My question , Thank you and Have a nice day

Comment: I was busy otherwise. However, nice to hear you could do it yourself.

Comment: @SIM No, Problem Thank you anyway :-) help me with upvote ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after trying to find a solution I created this and I know my code is correct

```
 Set elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

 For Each element In elements
 If element.getAttribute("class") = "onglet" Then
    If element.href = "Internal 
    PortXXXX/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do?fromSelect=true" Then
        element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
End If
Next element
```

this solution worked perfectly for me

```
For Each l In Doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.href = "h/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do?fromSelect=true" 
 Then
 l.Click
 end if 
Next
```

Best Regards

POLOS

Answer (score 0):

With a CSS selector

```
a.onglet[href*="/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do?"]
```

[image: Item selected with CSS query]

The `"."` says class onglet and `"*"` href contains `/cmh....`

Code usage:

```
doc.querySelector("a.onglet[href*=""/cmh/consultation/preViewMODScheduling.do?""]").Click
```